# How to hide profiler / FPS counter / HUD when running Flutter app on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, metal

I am running a flutter app on my iPhone from Android Studio, and there is this FPS counter / performance profiler view in the corner that I can't seem to get rid of (see screenshot below).

It does not appear when running in the iOS simulator or in Chrome.

I've tried running "flutter run —release" — that gets rid of the debug banner of course, but not this profiler thing.

I'm not a flutter developer—I got here from trying to load a build created by another developer. I installed android studio and followed the "flutter doctor" instructions until I got to this point.

The profiler shows things such as FPS, "Pre", GPU, Mem.

I am not sure if this is specific to Flutter, Android Studio, or Xcode.

Environment:

- Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
- Xcode 14.2
- M1 Mac, iPhone 12 mini running iOS 16

[image: iPhone screenshot, showing the profiler in the corner.]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough description, which made this searchable.  It's otherwise impossible to work your way backwards if you didn't know about this dev feature beforehand.

Comment: @electromaggot Thanks for sharing! This Q&A got quite a few downvotes when I first posted it, for whatever reason. I tried to be thorough in case anyone else came across this; glad I was able to help you out!

Comment: The downvotes confuse me too (wish I could boost your post past zero; it was indeed helpful).  Typical of the bad attitude on SO which has driven people away.  In my case, I was using a shared device and someone else had enabled this feature.  I looked all through the Xcode project to see what might be turning it on.  I was flummoxed and had no way to figure this out otherwise.  Apple's documentation on it is sparse.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this thing is Apple's **Metal Performance HUD**, which is referred to as the "Graphics HUD" in iOS's "Settings -> Developer" menu.

I unwittingly enabled it months ago when exploring the new iOS 16 Developer settings. The HUD did not appear for me at that time because the project I was working on did not use Metal. *Flutter does.*

This became apparent to me when I observed that "metal-HUD" was appearing in my Android Studio console when running the Flutter app on my iPhone.

Apple Developer video: [Discover Metal Performance HUD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/110339/)

[image: The "Show Graphics HUD" setting as shown in the iOS Developer Settings]

[image: The resultant HUD as shown in an app that uses Metal.]